# Help Identify N-MOSFET labeled “540N 3811g” for monitor repair

Tags: mosfet, identification

Could somebody please help me identify this n-mosfet? the pcb belongs to a qnix QX2710. I didn't found any datasheet\or specific information about it.[image]

*i created another thead with a correctly formulated question

Comment: What i know is that the board http://i.stack.imgur.com/IOylY.jpg has plenty of clones "thanks goes to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/54580/respawned-fluff"

Comment: Pretty bad resolution and angle, but I would say it reads 640N

Comment: yep i can confirm that in person says 540n

Comment: *shrug* 640n would have made more sense as they make them in 263 but 540n seems to come only in 220

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i'll make a better photo asap

Comment: @Andyaka: looks like I found an even better fitting dupe ^^

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is [this MOSFET: IRF540NS](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf540nspbf.pdf).

Comment: thank you guys, sorry for opening another thead but the other was closed. So i should simply go with the original "cloned" mosfet as reference?